# openoffice document (odt) to PDF with command line on Linux?

Tags: php, pdf, openoffice.org

we are building a PHP script that we need at work to create reports in PDFs

the reports will be created by using templates from postgrSQL.

so far I found that it can be done with the use of php and odt (openoffice) files [http://www.odtphp.com/]  (do you have any other suggestions?)

now how I can convert the results to PDF so teachers will get the final reports as PDF

any tips? the server has no GUI and I want to make it as simple as possible

we tried using PHP to PDF directly with FPDF [http://www.fpdf.org/] but it is really a CPU killer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter

this may help you, it needs to start OpenOffice as service, and the python script is merely utilizing its api, maybe you can write one in PHP too

Comment: Thanks, so I can not avoid installing OpenOffice!?!