# How do i use php to communicate with openoffice

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, openoffice.org

I am having ubuntu and have openoffice installed. Is there any way I can use php to convert my docs to odf? Is there any way to make php communicate with installed app?

Comment: Is this user name necessary?

Comment: Stuck, I can only change in 30days it seems

Comment: possible duplicate of [openoffice document (odt) to PDF with commad line on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832535/openoffice-document-odt-to-pdf-with-commad-line-on-linux)

Comment: It's not really a duplicate, but the link provided in the answer mario linked to will be your best bet : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832535/openoffice-document-odt-to-pdf-with-commad-line-on-linux/2832567#2832567

Comment: What do you mean by "communicate" ? If you want to generate files with PHP that are readable with OpenOffice, just use [CSV](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Answer (score 4):

Everything you need is **PyODConverter** (http://artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter)

It is simple and fast way to convert documents using OpenOffice/LibreOffice via command line. You can pass the command from PHP using exec()

1) Start Openoffice on server as a service using `libreoffice -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard`. Change command "libreoffice" to "soffice" (for openoffice, if you have one).

2) Download DocumentConverter.py and use it like this: `python DocumentConverter.py test.docx test.odf`

And that's it.