# Are their any free PHP librarys to convert PPT or ODT to PDF

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, open-source, document-conversion

I'm working on a document manager on a shared hosting account (linux) which I don't have command-line access too.

When people upload presentations I need to convert them to PDF for people to download. I have read that there is a way to do this by installing headless open office but I'm not going to be able do that on this server.

Are there any free php libraries that can manage the document conversion?

Cheers!

Comment: I doubt there's any /pure/ PHP libraries, but there very well might be PHP wrapper libraries around C/C++ libraries that do the conversion... but, if you can't install headless open office, you probably couldn't use those either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any free php libraries that can manage the document conversion?

I don't think so. This is way too complex a task for a PHP script. The script would have to emulate what OpenOffice already does. Headless Open Office is indeed the way to go here.

If you're willing to rely on a third party service, and pay money, I've seen some conversion services around that offer the functions of OpenOffice through a web service.

Comment: shucks... ahh well, I had a feeling this may be the case but remained hopeful anyway. Thanks Pekka... Its a shame, I have found loads of libraries for converting doc to pdf but presentations seams to be the problem.

Comment: It isn't "way too complex"... it's just a matter of having the time to implement all the functionality needed in PHPPowerPoint, sadly time that I don't have at the moment... but using headless OpenOffice via PUNO - http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05 - is certainly the best option at the moment

Comment: anyone found a PHP solution so far?

Answer (score 0):

I'll echo the sentiments of others (this is asking a bit much of PHP), however, you might be able  to work around shared hosting issue but relying on a third-party server to do the conversion for you. Install Open Office (and any other software you need) on another server and set up an API that will accept an incoming ppt and return the converted pdf. Perhaps not what you're looking for, but it's a functional work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not the least bit familiar w/any of these.

1. [Convert ppt to pdf in php linux](http://samsami2u.wordpress.com/2008/07/24/convert-ppt-to-pdf-in-php-linux/)
2. Write code to read in PPT using [PHPPowerpoint](http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/) and output it using [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)
3. Look at this SO discussion [openoffice document (odt) to PDF with commad line on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832535/openoffice-document-odt-to-pdf-with-commad-line-on-linux)